# Looping Table Body With Two Rows in Clojurescript / Reagent

Tags: html, clojurescript, reagent

I'm having trouble getting my table body to line up properly using clojurescript / reagent.  I'm actually not sure if this is me not understanding what to do in html or what...

Currently I display the table body using a loop

```
(defn table-body [list-of-maps] 
[:tbody
  (for [one-map list-of-maps]
     [:tbody
      [:tr
       [:td (:key1 one-map)]
       [:td (:key2 one-map)]
       [:td (:key3 one-map)]
       [:td (:key4 one-map)]
       [:td (:key5 one-map)]
       [:td (:key6 one-map)]
       [:td (:key7 one-map)]]
      [:tr
       [:td (:key8 one-map)]]])])
```

The problem is that I need to group both outside the for and inside the for using some html element, right?  If I use [:tbody] on both it will mess up the alignment with the [:thead] section.  If I use an element other than tbody then it creates all kinds of other issues.  Everything looks fine if I remove the [:tbody] in the for loop and the last [:tr].

Edit:  I've currently narrowed down the problem a lot.  My app ajax gets and derefs data involved with the table.  On this re-render the formatting of the table gets messed up.

Edit2:  I've found the issue.

```
(defn test-body [list-of-maps]
[:tbody
  (for [one-map @list-of-maps]
     [:tbody
      [:tr
       [:td (:key1 one-map)]
       [:td (:key2 one-map)]
       [:td (:key3 one-map)]
       [:td (:key4 one-map)]
       [:td (:key5 one-map)]
       [:td (:key6 one-map)]
       [:td (:key7 one-map)]]
      [:tr
       [:td (:key8 one-map)]]])])

(defn test-head []
  [:thead
   [:th "key1"]
   [:th "key2"]
   [:th "key3"]
   [:th "key4"]
   [:th "key5"]
   [:th "key6"]
   [:th "key7"]])

(defn test55 []
  (let [list-of-maps (reagent/atom [])]
    (js/setTimeout (fn [] (reset! list-of-maps '({:key1 "a1" :key2 "a2" :key3 "a3" :key4 "a4" :key5 "a5" :key6 "a6" :key7 "a7" :key8 "a8"} {:key1 "b1" :key2 "b2" :key3 "b3" :key4 "b4" :key5 "b5" :key6 "b6" :key7 "b7" :key8 "b8"}))) 3000)
    [:table
     [test-head]
     [test-body list-of-maps]]))
```

When the list-of-maps re-renders the alignment of the table breaks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this problem can be solved by thinking about things just simply as vectors.  What vector do you want the end result to look like?

```
[:tbody 
   [:tr 
      [:td "a1"] [:td "a2"] [:td "a3"] [:td "a4"] [:td "a5"] [:td "a6"] [:td "a7"]] 
   [:tr 
      [:td "a8"]] 
   [:tr 
      [:td "b1"] [:td "b2"] [:td "b3"] [:td "b4"] [:td "b5"] [:td "b6"] [:td "b7"]] 
   [:tr 
      [:td "b8"]]]
```

So with this as our goal, we set out to have the body function create this.

```
(defn test-body [list-of-maps]
  (into [] (concat [:tbody] (apply concat (for [one-map @list-of-maps]
                                            [
                                             [:tr
                                              [:td (:key1 one-map)]
                                              [:td (:key2 one-map)]
                                              [:td (:key3 one-map)]
                                              [:td (:key4 one-map)]
                                              [:td (:key5 one-map)]
                                              [:td (:key6 one-map)]
                                              [:td (:key7 one-map)]]
                                             [:tr
                                              [:td (:key8 one-map)]]])))))
```

This is my solution.  There may be a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is unequal number of cells in the rows. HTML `TD` element has `COLSPAN` attribute. Try setting in the last row, to the number of cells in the above rows.

```
(defn test-body
  [list-of-maps]
  [:tbody
    (for [one-map @list-of-maps]
       [:tbody
        [:tr
         [:td (:key1 one-map)]
         [:td (:key2 one-map)]
         [:td (:key3 one-map)]
         [:td (:key4 one-map)]
         [:td (:key5 one-map)]
         [:td (:key6 one-map)]
         [:td (:key7 one-map)]]
        [:tr
         [:td {:colspan 7} (:key8 one-map)]]])])
```